# 'type_cast_required' is undefined messagge in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, flask

I have created a databse in Postgresql. I am trying to use pgadmin to add new record to a table, however I am getting a messagge: 'type_cast_required' is undefined.

Screen shot:

[image: 1]

I have looked across the web for what this message means however I have not found anything.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE VIEW` statement that defined `public."mailing list"`?

Comment: I dont know. How do I find that out? 

PS. I receive the same messagge for every table.

Comment: You could connect with `psql` and type `\d public."mailing list"`.

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin bug. This should have been fixed as of version pgAdmin 4.22. For more details see this [issue](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/5600). You will need a Postgres community account to view issue.